# MDX Calculated member with filter

Tags: ssas, mdx, calculated-field, cube-script

Being pretty new to MDX so this might be a rookie question. But have not been able to "translate" any answers to a solution!

I have a Measure which Counts my number of rows called [Measures].[Fact Count]

I also have a Dimension called [Document] which has a field called [Is Completed].

The [Document].[Is Completed] can have one of two values: [Yes] or [No].

The [Document] dimension does have several other fields, like [Document Type]

What I would like to ask a question like "How big a percentage of my different document types have been completed".

I have tried making a [Completed Count] like this:

```
([Measures].[Fact Count],
[Document].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
```

and then use it like:

```
[Measures].[Completed Count]/[Measures].[Fact Count]*100
```

But (of course) the [Completed Count] then takes all my completed documents instead of only those per e.g. [Document Type]

Hope this makes sense to someone!

Comment: are you developing within the cube, or are you creating a script that queries a cube i.e. are you creating a cube?

Comment: I am making my calculated member in my multidimensional cube. Na Query from SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, got the solution!

Since my Dimension contains "Yes" or "No" values, I can convert them to 1 and 0 and add them to my [Measures] as [Measures].[Is Completed Sum]. And as the name says: I'll sum the values.

Then the calculation is straight forward:

```
[Measures].[Is Completed Sum]/
[Measures].[Fact Count]*100
```

or if I will make sure not to divide by 0:

```
iif(
[Measures].[Fact Count] = 0,
null,
[Measures].[Is Completed Sum]/
[Measures].[Fact Count]*100
)
```

I will still keep my Yes/no's in the Dimension as well since I can use them as filters when needed.

whytheq, thank you very much for all your input! It was very valuable and made my brain spin in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the other side that needs to be more explicit?

```
(
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Document].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
/
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Document].[Is Completed].[All])
)
*100
```

If you have an attribute hierarchy for Is Completed try using that - probably like this...

```
(
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Is Completed].[Is Completed].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
/
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Is Completed].[Is Completed].[All])
)
*100
```

or this

```
(
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Is Completed].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
/
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Is Completed].[All])
)
*100
```

If you change the measure to the following and put Yes | No ON COLUMNS do you start to get the correct results?

```
(
 ([Measures].[Fact Count])
/
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Document].[Is Completed].[All])
)
*100
```

Comment: Almost - but not right there. The number I get is a "fixed" number. Meaning that all my Document Types is having the same percentage (which is the TOTAL number of completed Documents compared to the TOTAL number of Documents). I should mention that I make the calculation in my cube but I make my Query from Excel which is connected to the cube.

Comment: ah - think i have an idea - do you have an attribute hierarchy for [Is Completed] ? try swapping that in instead of using the multi-level User Hierarchy Document

Comment: Nope - there is no hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think that is possible: User Hierarchies are created from Attribute Hierarchies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-olap-logical-dimension-objects/attributes-and-attribute-hierarchies?view=sql-analysis-services-2017

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SCOPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/mdx-scripting-scope?view=sql-analysis-services-2017) it.
(stole the code from whytheq, i think hes got the right answer)

```
SCOPE ([Document].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
THIS = (
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Document].[Is Completed].&[Yes])
/
 ([Measures].[Fact Count],
  [Document].[Is Completed].[All])
)
*100
END SCOPE
```

Regarding

> Since my Dimension contains "Yes" or "No" values, I can convert them to 1 and 0
>   You could improve your model and add a new Column Value to your Dimension.

And actually get the 1 and 0 with just < Member>.[VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/value-mdx?view=sql-analysis-services-2017)